# Logging Apache instance name in Django logger

Tags: python, django, apache, logging

We use the Django logging module for our Django app, which runs on a couple of Apache instances on a server; each instance is a different setup, like production/staging/development/testing. How do I log the Apache instance name in the logger? Currently, I've tried this, and it only logs the machine name.

```
try:
    HOSTNAME = socket.gethostname()
except:
    HOSTNAME = 'localhost'

LOGGING = {
    'formatters': {
                  'standard': {
                              'format': '%(asctime)s [' + HOSTNAME + '] [%(levelname)s]:[%(lineno)s] - %(message)s'
                               },
    }
}
```

How do I identify the Apache instance here?